# Find all polynomials such that $P (x) = (x-P (0))(x-P (1))...(x-P (n-1))$

Tags: functions, polynomials

Find all polynomials $P(x)$ of degree $n>0$ with integer coefficients such that, for every real number $x$, we have:
$$P(x) = (x-P (0))(x-P (1))...(x-P (n-1)) $$

I thought that i proved that $P(0) = 0$ but actually the conclusion was wrong, as showed in the comments. I'm back to the incial point.

I don't now how to proceed, can somebody help me?

Comment: Your conclusion for the case $P(0)\ne 0$ is wrong. It should be $P(1)\cdots P(n-1)=(-1)^n$ instead of $P(1)\cdots P(n-1)=(-1)^{1-n}$.

Comment: @kcco, there are $n$ parantheses, so degree is $n$ !

Comment: @kccu It has degree $n$... Goes from 0 to $n-1$.

Comment: @Gae. S you are right, i edited the post, thanks.

Comment: If you plug $P(1)\cdots P(n-1)=(-1)^n$ back into the original evaluation of $P(0)$, you don't obtain $P(0)=(-1)^nP(0)$, but $P(0)=(-1)^{2n}P(0)$, which is just the tautology $P(0)=P(0)$.

Comment: Right, i'm really confused hahaha, sorry.

Comment: Suppose $P(k) = k$ for some $k>0$. Then $k = P(k) = (k-P(0))\cdots (k-P(k))\cdots (k-P(n-1)) = 0$ is a contradiction. Therefore $P(k)\neq k$ for all $k>0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** If $n=1$, it's easy to see that the only solution is $P(x)=x$.

**2.** If $n \geq 2$, set $x=0$:

$$P(0)=(-1)^n\cdot P(0)\cdot P(1)\cdot \ldots \cdot P(n-1)$$

If $P(0)$ is non-zero, we have

$$ P(1)\cdot P(2) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(n-1)=(-1)^{n+1}$$

This means that all the values $P(1), P(2), \ldots, P(n)$ are $\pm 1$. However, none of this values can be $1$, because by setting $x = 1$, we would have $P(1)=0$. This means they are all $-1$, so

$$P(x)=[x-P(0)]\cdot (x+1)^{n-1}$$

Now setting $x=1$ we get

$$-1=P(1)=2^{n-1}\cdot [1-P(0)]$$

which is false. This means we must have $P(0) = 0$. Therefore the given relation writes as

$$P(x)=x(x-P(1))(x-P(2))\cdot\ldots \cdot(x-P(n-1))$$

Now setting $x=1$ gives

$$(1-P(1))(1-P(2))\cdot \ldots \cdot(1-P(n-1))=P(1) $$

However, since $\gcd(P(1),1-P(1))=1$, we must have either $P(1)=0$ or $P(1)=2$.

If $P(1) = 0$, we have $P(i)=1$ for some $2\leq i \leq n-1$, but setting $x=i$ gives

$$1=i^2(i-1)(i-P(2))\cdot \ldots \cdot(i-P(n-1))$$

which is false again.

If $P(1) = 2$ we get

$$(1-P(2))\cdot \ldots \cdot(1-P(n-1))=-2$$

None of these factors can be $1$ (similar reasoning as previously), so $P(i)=3$ for some $i$ and $P(j)=0$, for $2\leq j \leq n,\ j\neq i$. We get $P(x)=x^{n-2}(x-2)(x-3)$, which is not a solution.

In conclusion, the only solution is $P(x) = x$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, I think you solved a much broader problem :)

Comment: I totally missed the part about integer coefficients, lol.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this answer does not answer the problem as stated. I am ignoring the restriction that the coefficients must be integers, and the result is actually really interesting, so I am leaving it as a response, as it does show there are no solutions with integer coefficients possible for $n=2,n=3$

Consider $n=1$: $P(x) = x-P(0)$ and $P(0) = -P(0) \Longrightarrow P(0) = 0$ shows that $P(x) = x$.

Consider $n=2$: $P(x) = (x-P(0))(x-P(1))$. Plug in $x=0$:

$$P(0) = P(0)P(1) \Longrightarrow P(0)(P(1)-1) = 0 \Longrightarrow P(0) = 0 \text{ or } P(1) = 1$$

From my comment above, $P(1) \neq 1$. Therefore $P(0) = 0$. This gives $P(1) = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

The only possible polynomial of degree 2 is $$P(x) = x\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$

Consider $n=3$: $P(x) = (x-P(0))(x-P(1))(x-P(2))$. Plug in $x=0$:

$$P(0) = -P(0)P(1)P(2) \Longrightarrow P(0)(1+P(1)P(2)) = 0 \Longrightarrow P(0) = 0\text{ or } P(1)P(2) = -1$$

Suppose $P(0) = 0$. Then $P(x) = x(x-P(1))(x-P(2))$. Plug in $x=1$:
$$P(1) = 1-P(1)-P(2)+P(1)P(2) \Longrightarrow P(2)-1 = P(1)(P(2)-2)$$

Since $P(2) \neq 2$, we have $P(1) = \dfrac{P(2)-1}{P(2)-2}$

Plugging in $x=2$ gives $$P(2) = 2\left(2-\dfrac{P(2)-1}{P(2)-2}\right)(2-P(2)) = 6-2P(2) \Longrightarrow P(2) = 2$$

This is, of course, a contradiction.

Next, suppose $P(1)P(2) = -1$

At $x=0$, $P(0) = -P(0)P(1)P(2) = P(0)$ is true for any $P(0)$.

At $x=1$:

$$\begin{align*}P(1) & = (1-P(0))(1-P(1))(1-P(2)) \\ & = 1-P(0)-P(1)-P(2)+P(0)P(1)+P(0)P(2)+P(1)P(2)-P(0)P(1)P(2) \\ & = -P(1)-P(2)+P(0)P(1)+P(0)P(2)\end{align*}$$

At $x=2$:
$$\begin{align*}P(2) & = (2-P(0))(2-P(1))(2-P(2)) \\ & = 8-4P(0)-4P(1)-4P(2)+2P(0)P(1)+2P(0)P(2)+2P(1)P(2)-P(0)P(1)P(2) \\ & = 6-3P(0)-4P(1)-4P(2)+2P(0)P(1)+2P(0)P(2)\end{align*}$$

Rearranging, we have:

$$\begin{align*}P(1)P(2) & = -1 \\ 2P(1)+P(2) & = P(0)(P(1)+P(2)) \\ 5P(2)+4P(1)+3P(0) & = 6+2P(0)(P(1)+P(2))\end{align*}$$

Solving gives:

$$P(0) = \dfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}, P(1) = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, P(2) = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \\ P(0) = \dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}, P(1) = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}, P(2) = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

This gives two solutions for $n=3$:

$$P(x) = \left(x-\dfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x-\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \\ P(x) = \left(x-\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x-\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$

This does not look to have a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that if $P(0)\ne 0$, one has $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}P(k)=(-1)^n,$$ so that even number of $P(k)$'s $(k\ge 1)$are $1$ and the rest are $-1$, so that $P(x)$ can be of the form $(x-P(0))(x-1)^e(x+1)^{n-1-e}$, for some $e=2,4,6,\cdots$. However, in that case, $P(k)=\pm 1$ for $k=1,2,\cdots,n-1$, and therefore putting $x=k, k\in \{1,2,\cdots,n-1\}$ gives $$\pm 1=(k-P(0))(k-1)^e(k+1)^{n-1-e},$$ which is absurd. Therefore, one must have $P(0)=0$. Consequently, $$P(x)=x(x-P(1))\cdots(x-P(n-1)).$$ Now note that for any $k\ge 1$, $$P(k) = k(k-P(1))\cdots(k-P(k))\cdots(k-P(n-1))\\\implies k|P(k),\ k-P(k)|P(k).$$ Therefore, there are integers $r,s$ such that $P(k)=kr,\ P(k)=s(k-P(s))$. Therefore, $kr=s(k-kr)\implies s(1-r)=r\implies 1-r=\pm 1\implies r=0,2$ and $s=0,-2$. Hence, either $P(k)=0$, or $P(k)=2k$. Now, let $P(k)=2k$ for some $k\ge 1$. Then, $$2k=P(k)=k(k-P(1))\cdots(k-P(k))\cdots(k-P(n-1))\\\implies -2=k(k-P(1))\cdots(k-P(k-1))\cdots (k-P(n-1))\\\implies k=1,2.$$ However, in that case, $P(k)=0$ for all $k\ge 3$, so that $$P(x)=x^{n-2}(x-P(1))(x-P(2))\implies 0=P(3)=3^{n-2}(3-P(1))(3-P(2)),$$ which yields a contradiction. Therefore, one must have, $P(k)=0$ for all $k\ge 1$. Therefore, $P(x)=x^n$. However, this works only when $n=1$. Therefore, the only solution is $P(x)=x$.